# Length of string within a list of strings python

Tags: python, list

I'm iterating over a list that I'm trying to extract data from that looks like this:

```
for i in lst: 
    print(i.split('-'))


... output

['a', 'doa', 'a', 'h5t']
['a', 'rne']
['a', 'ece']
['a', 'ece']
['a', 'tnt', 'c', 'doa', 'd', 'nvc', 'a', 'nnm', 'a', 'h5t']
['a', 'tps']
```

My goal is to extract all the strings within each list that 3 characters long.  If I do

```
len(i.split('-'))
```

in which case the above would look like:

```
4
2
2
2
10
2
```

in the loop than I just get the length of each unique string in the list. My question is how can I get a count of the characters in each string in each list?

EDIT:

The output should look like:

```
['doa', 'h5t']
['rne']
['ece']
['ece']
['tnt', 'doa', 'nvc', 'nnm', 'h5t']
['tps']
```

Comment: What would be the required output given the example data you have implied? Ok, got it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My goal is to extract all the strings within each list that 3 characters long.

A nested list comprehensions will do the trick.

```
>>> l = ['a-bc-def-ghij-klm', 'abc-de' 'fg-hi']
>>> [[x for x in s.split('-') if len(x) == 3] for s in l]
[['def', 'klm'], ['abc']]
```

Comment: @schwobaseggl yup, fixed.

Comment: While I like the list-comp approach, a list comp within a list comp tends to be ugly.  Also since OP edited his original post, it doesn't look like he wants a nested list.

Comment: @BrianM.Sheldon I disagree. This is well within PEP8 line length and very readable. More so, I'd suggest, than a nested loop where the list variable declaration and the `append` calls are 3 lines apart.

Comment: An alternative would be `[list(filter(lambda x: len(x) == 3, s.split('-'))) for s in l]` but I personally don't like it.

Comment: @timgeb haha, but reality is that filter is faster in py3 =))

Comment: @BrianM.Sheldon Double nesting of comprehensions / generators is ok, but I'll agree that deeper nesting ought to be split up, unless you're doing code golf.

Answer (score 2):

This code:

```
lst = ['a-doa-a-h2t','a-rne','a-ece','a-ece','a-tnt-c-doa-d-nvc-a-nnm-a-h5t','a-tps']
for item in lst:
    words = item.split('-')
    print([word for word in words if len(word) == 3])
```

produces output something like your requirement:

```
['doa', 'h2t']
['rne']
['ece']
['ece']
['tnt', 'doa', 'nvc', 'nnm', 'h5t']
['tps']
```

Comment: really ugly, with list generator in print

Comment: Sure is. This seems to be the way the kids are writing code these days! But, hey, that is the requirement of the OP.

Comment: I don't think it's ugly and I will punish you with an upvote.

Answer (score -1):

You need another loop to extract each word in the split like so:

```
for item in lst:
  for word in item.split('-'):
    if len(word) == 3:
      print(word)
```

Comment: I chose to save the split strings into a substrings variable with the assumption that he might need it later, if not then your solution is definitely cleaner.